# "$ is not defined" jQuery bottom with PHP include

Tags: php, jquery

They are good practices put jQuery the bottom of the page, before the `</ body>`, but when you have an include PHP in the middle of the page and in this `include` I have that jQuery code like this:

```
[code of index.php]
[include]
<script>
$(function() {
        <?php
        echo "$('#".$_SESSION['user']['flags']."').attr('selected', true);";
        ?>
    });
</script>
[/include]
[code of index.php including jQuery.js here before </body>]
```

Firebug tells me that `$ is not defined`. I used "defer" but it does not work either. I searched Stackoverflow but do not know how to fix it.

Here my code:

index.php

```
<!doctype html>
    <html class="no-js" lang="es">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="robots" content="noodp, noydir">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body id="body">
    <?php
      include './step1.php';
     ?>
     <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

step1.php

```
<script>
$(function() {
        <?php
        echo "$('#".$_SESSION['user']['flags']."').attr('selected', true);";
        ?>
    });
</script>
```

Comment: 1st include jQuery library then jQuery code.

Comment: Move the jQuery include to the top of the body. Or anywhere before the spot where you try to use it.

Comment: so shouldn't you just include **JQuery** in the **head** now ? it's all about use cases. Good practices can't be always used .

Comment: Please replace $ to jQuery , and then try

Comment: Can  you show the place and code of where and how you include the jQuery file in index.php?

Comment: @ErnestoCCalienteToporaz i'll edit my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you replace the "$(function(){" section with window.onload you can ensure that all script files have been loaded before attempting to fire your function.

However, be aware that this fires much later that jQuery's document.ready. jQuery's method fires when the dom is loaded whereas window.onload waits until the whole document and it's scripts have been loaded.

More info and example here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

Answer (score 0):

You included the jQuery.js after the inclusion of that script. Move your jQuery.js include above include statement that contains your js code.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to the problem**:
You have included the step1.php before including jQuery.js. This is why it won't work. Include jQuery.js before including step1.php.

**Answer regarding jQuery in end of HTML body**: 
Yes, it's a good practice but that seems to me as a micro-optimization. As it would speed up the loadtime. But you can only do that if you include your written jQuery code after including the actual jQuery.js library. Since you're not able to do that in the current contruction, you need to change the order to make it work.

**Otherwise general debugging techniques apply:**

1. Check your browser. Right click. Inspect element. Open tab network. Make sure the jQuery.js file is really included so you'll have a HTTP status 200 code on this request.
2. Make sure jQuery is really inside jQuery.js and the file is not empty or having other contents.
3. Make sure jQuery not included twice.

Also checkout:

- https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/
- http://www.sitepoint.com/types-document-ready/

or try:

`jQuery(document).ready(function(){  /* [code here] */ });`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Doesn't work. I attached these screenshots. 

1. Check my browser: http://imgur.com/a/Vc60t
2. Yes, is jQuery.min.js hosted on Google.
4. I tried but Firebug tells me the same: http://imgur.com/TLnU96w

Comment: @ErnestoCCalienteToporaz try `jQuery.noconflict();`

Comment: It is not necessary to follow the good practice to include jQuery in the end, before the body?

Comment: thanks for your answers. Window.onload does works perfectly too without change jQuery to top.

Comment: @ErnestoCCalienteToporaz inside window.onload you should still use a jQuery ready call and then your code. Otherwise there is a chance that the files are loaded but the DOM isn't.